# Convergence of double power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When does the series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n^{n^{\alpha}}-1)
\end{equation}
converge? Throught the limit test, I can see that foor all $\alpha$$\geq$0 this series diverges. I have problems with all the other cases, please help.

Comment: I've tried using the integral test a then comparing the integral to
\begin{equation}
\int x^{\alpha}
\end{equation}
But I have problem proving that $x^{\alpha}$ behaves like $x^{n^{\alpha}}$-1 for large x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For $\alpha  < 0$,
$$
n^{n^\alpha  }  - 1 = \exp \left( {\frac{{\log n}}{{n^{\left| \alpha  \right|} }}} \right) - 1 > 1 + \frac{{\log n}}{{n^{\left| \alpha  \right|} }} - 1 = \frac{{\log n}}{{n^{\left| \alpha  \right|} }},
$$
for all $n\geq 1$. Also, for sufficiently large $n$,
$$
n^{n^\alpha  }  - 1 = \exp \left( {\frac{{\log n}}{{n^{\left| \alpha  \right|} }}} \right) - 1 < 1 + 2\frac{{\log n}}{{n^{\left| \alpha  \right|} }} - 1 = 2\frac{{\log n}}{{n^{\left| \alpha  \right|} }} .
$$

Comment: Yes this helped alot, sorry for the late reply........